# When converting a mysql time in php I always get 16:00:20, regardless of the mysql time

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I am having trouble with converting time, when I use the date() function on a mysql timestamp, it only returns 16:00.

Am I using the date() function wrong?

PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$date = date('H:i:s A'); 
echo "System: $date <br />";

$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$query = "SELECT CURTIME() as timestamp";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "DB CurTime: ".$row["timestamp"]."<br />";
echo "DB CurTime Converted: ".date("H:i:s A",$row["timestamp"]);
```

OUTPUT:

> System: 20:41:23 PM
>
> DB CurTime: 20:41:23
>
> DB CurTime Converted: 16:00:20 PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CURTIME()` does not return the UNIX timestamp in seconds. You'll need to run a `strtotime()` on it.

Your last line should read:

```
echo "DB CurTime Converted: ".date("H:i:s A", strtotime($row["timestamp"]));
```

On another note, [Kalium's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225744/when-converting-a-mysql-time-in-php-i-always-get-160020-regardless-of-the-mysq/3225768#3225768) also has information worth considering.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are using `date()` wrong. `date()` accepts a second argument in the form of a UNIX timestamp, but that's not what you're handing it.

Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `CURTIME()` when fetching from MySQL, although I do wonder why you're getting the time from MySQL instead of using PHP's perfectly good `time()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo "DB CurTime Converted: ".date("H:i:s A",strtotime($row["timestamp"]));
```

edit - oops, too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to convert the time using unix_timestamp() mysql function or convert the time in PHP with strtotime().

**Solution 1** change your query

```
$query = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME()) as timestamp";
```

I did not test this query, but i believe it will work.

**Solution 2:** change your last line

```
echo "DB CurTime Converted: ".date("H:i:s A",strtotime($row["timestamp"]));
```

you can try anyone! both is supposed to produce same result!